# Need help creating this SELECT procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have three tables which are Complaint, ComplaintDetail and Person.

```
create table Complaint (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    complaintName varchar(50),
    datetime datetime,
    place nvarchar(MAX),
    declarantName nvarchar(50),
    detail nvarchar(MAX),
    verifyStatus bit   /* approved or not */
)
go

create table ComplaintDetail (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    personId int,
    constraint cdp foreign key (personId) references Person(id),
    compId int,
    constraint cpc foreign key (compId) references Complaint(id),
    crimeType nvarchar(50)
)
go

create table Person (
    id int primary key,
    name nvarchar(50),
    gender bit NOT NULL,
    dob date,
    address nvarchar(MAX),
    image varchar(100),
    nationality varchar(50),
    job varchar(20),
    alive bit DEFAULT 1
)
```

I want to create a **SELECT** procedure to find all the Complaints that **doesn't** link with that Person.id

I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE PROC findExcludedComplaints
    @personID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Complaint
    INNER JOIN ComplaintDetail ON Complaint.id = ComplaintDetail.compId
    INNER JOIN Person ON ComplaintDetail.personId != Person.id
    WHERE Person.id = @personID
END
GO
```

Comment: Please be more specific than 'it doesn't work'

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you can use a `LEFT JOIN` on Person and ComplaintDetail like this

```
LEFT JOIN Person ON ComplaintDetail.personId = Person.id
```

and the amend the `WHERE` with

```
AND ComplaintDetail.personId IS NULL
```

Comment: Note that the condition Person.id = @personID needs to be in the left join and not in the where clause for this option to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there are two ways to read your question. Your existing query is correct for one of them.

The first interpretation is: "Get me all the information about the person matching the `@personId` parameter, and also find me all of the column values from the complaints and complaint details that aren't related to that person."

The second interpretation is: "Get me the all of the complaints which aren't related to `@personId`, and get me the details of the person who *is* related to that complaint".

So the difference is just which values you get from the `person` table: The values of the person matching `@personId`, versus the values for the person who is actually related to the complaint, and does not match `@personId`.

Your existing query will correctly give you the first result, so I guess you don't want that. So I deduce you must want the second result. That would be:

```
select  * -- you shouldn't really use select *
from    Person            p
join    ComplaintDetails  d on d.personId = p.id
join    Complaints        c on c.id = d.compId
where   p.id != @personId
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a SELECT procedure to find all the Complaints that doesn't link with that Person.id

Use a `cross join` to generate all combinations of persons and complaints.  Then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select p.*, c.*
from persons p cross join
     complaints c left join
     complaintdetail cd
     on cd.person_id = p.id and cd.complaint_id = c.id
where cd.id is null;
```